# Error in Creating First App in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working with the first app in android studio and it shows 7 errors. This is the first time I use Android Studio/

[image]

It should be no error since I just started using it and it is freshly installed in my computer

Comment: There is option called "Make Project" under Build menu. (Keyboard shortcut: Ctrl + F9). Check if error is there after building.

Comment: can you display your code and the 7 errors

Comment: Show the errors plese!

Answer (score 0):

To solve any issue in android studio,click on error and press Alt+Enter it will suggest you what kind of query is there.

Here in your code you can see error in build part at below, if it not sowing there than you can  should click on error and press Alt+Enter, add class or package android studio suggesting, it will solve your error.

if it doesn't solve your error than you can go to File menu --> Invalid Caches and Restart, it will may solve.

I hope this will help you!